# Creating Mysql Table From Array Values

Tags: php, mysql

I had tried to Create a Mysql Table using the values of an array,this is my code

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE clinical_time (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ';

foreach($temparray as $field) {
    $sql .= ' ' . $field . ' VARCHAR( 40 ),';
}
$sql .= ' PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ))';
$i = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if($i != 0) {
    echo '<script>alert("Table Created SUCCESFULLY")</script>';
}
else {
    echo '<script>alert("ERROR")</script>';
}
```

This code shows no errors but table is not created...Can anyone help me with this,thanks in advance.

Comment: add  print result of $temparray  in your code

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: k tyteen i will use mysqli here after tnk u 4 answering

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE clinical_time (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ';
$temparray = array ("field1","field2","field3");
 foreach($temparray as $field)
    {
        $sql .= ' '.$field.' VARCHAR( 40 ),';
    }
        $sql .= ' PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ))';

echo $sql ;
```

The output is

```
CREATE TABLE clinical_time (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, field1 VARCHAR( 40 ), field2 VARCHAR( 40 ), field3 VARCHAR( 40 ), PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ))
```

Which I executed on mysql and table got created.

So may be something wrong with the array ?

Comment: it is not an answer of this question

Comment: @user2971084 can you print_r($temparray);  and let us know what you see ?

Answer (score 0):

For any problem like this, just echo the results of your SQL building before you send the query.

Looking at the constructed command you may immediately see the problem, if not then take it into your SQL client utility of choice and run the command in that and use it to identify and fix the problem.

Comment: Tnk u everyone for answering,i found the error,its in my array that contains numeric input.Because of that the table is not created.Now i prefixed a variable b4 that and my table gt created.Special tnks to Tim B 4 giving me a good answer,and rest others tnk u very much 4 answering to this query.